# Is it possible to configure api permission to Azure Active Directory app using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I have manually registered App in Azure Active Directory. To this App, I need to configure Microsoft Graph, Azure Key vault API's and set permissions to that.

Is it possible to configure API's and set permission to AAD app using powershell.
If possible , please provide me some info on how to achieve this

Comment: http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2017/09/19/create-azure-ad-app-registration-with-powershell-part-2 this looks right

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible through Powershell.
[This article](https://adatum.no/azure/azure-ad-application-using-powershell) explains how to create an Azure AD App in Powershell.

The rights for the app is done through a [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects) which can be set through Powershell as well.

You can also access and manipulate the [Key Vault through Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , in the above article new AAD app is created and permissions are set that is fine , what i am looking for is to set api permission on existing AAD app